# How does BigQuery integrate with Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

I started with Firebase and started needing more flexible query support like aggregations etc and found that BigQuery maybe able to fill that requirement.

I am wondering though, how does this work under the hood? Everytime data changes in Firebase, it gets replicated into BigQuery? Or does BigQuery query directly from Firebase?

If its replication, won't it be potentially slow?

Should I just start with BigQuery from the start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page has all the information you need. In short, you get daily exports of unsampled event data into BigQuery. This is done for you automatically. BQ is a SQL 2011 standard data warehouse. You can write your queries in SQL to obtain insights from it.

https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765?hl=en

Comment: To confirm my understanding, so my data will be synced regularly so its eventually consistent? Does it take 1 full day for my data to be synced to BQ (there was mentioned about intra-day sync)?

Comment: What you say is correct. They will improve more and more so data will be available more often than a day. But this is just proposed you should not trust it yet.